# Cannot Connect To Honeywell SL22 Captuvo Hardware

Tags: ios

I'm just getting started with Honeywell Captuvo SL22 and iPod Touch. I have successfully built and deployed the two included sample SDK apps (SDKTestSample and mPOS) on the device and they both work flawlessly. I am now trying to create my first simple test of the device but I am getting stuck trying to make the initial connection to the scanner hardware. I am using :

Xcode 6.1
SDK 2.19.742.XXXXX
Firmware Rev 45.12

I am deploying app directly to 5th gen iPod running IOS 7.0.4 and then running inserted into  sled.

Here is the code. Problem in my simple app is that connectionStatus always returns ProtocolConnectionStatusUnableToConnect so I can't go any further until I get this resolved.

Firmware version read by app is displayed correctly.

Any Ideas ?

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  ButtonTest
//
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Captuvo.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize Label1;
@synthesize Label2;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *FirmwareVersion = @"0.0";
    int connectionStatus;

    FirmwareVersion = [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice]  getCaptuvoFirmwareRevision];
    Label1.text = FirmwareVersion;


    Label2.Text = @"Captuvo Status";

    connectionStatus = [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice]  startDecoderHardware];

    switch (connectionStatus) {
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusConnected:
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusAlreadyConnected:
            NSLog(@"Connected!");
            Label2.text = @"Sled Connected";
            break;
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusBatteryDepleted:
            NSLog(@"Battery depleted!");
            Label2.text = @"Battery depleted!";
            break;
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusUnableToConnect:
            NSLog(@"Error connecting!");
            Label2.text = @"Error connecting!";
            break;
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusUnableToConnectIncompatiableSledFirmware:
            NSLog(@"Incompatible firmware!");
            Label2.text = @"Incompatible firmware!";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }



}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out this problem? Also did you ever figure out how to deploy directly from Xcode to the captuvo without unplugging

Answer (score 2):

This question is a little old, yet still relevant. This answer may not help the OP, but may help someone else down the road...

I had this same issue until I edited the Info.plist and added a property:

```
Supported external accessory protocols

-Item 0 : com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.decoder
-Item 1 : com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.pm
-Item 2 : com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.msr
```

What I really came here looking for, though, was an answer to @jamespick's question, asking if the OP had figured out how to deploy from Xcode without unplugging from the Captuvo sled. You would think that Xcode 7 would have wireless deploy/debugging, but no dice.